# WCF service taking userPincipleNname instead of passed in string as argument

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

This is a weird issue.  I am passing in strings into my service, and that string would be the username of the person logged into my website (via windows authorization).  I get the string from my website using

```
    HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString()
```

I parse it from the domain and just get the user Identity.  And then I call a wcf service whose contract is similar to this...

```
    generalWCFContractImplementation(string userID);
```

Now, you would think it would pass in the string that I sent it... However, that is indeed not the case.  After doing some debugging, I found out that the string that is being passed in is the userPrincipleName that I am using to setup the WCF connection!  Now why on earth would it do that?  I am checking all throughout my code to see if accidentally change the userID in some way, but I check as soon as I enter the function what the value of the ID is, and it is the userPrincipleName!  I am extremely confused about what is going on here.  Does anybody have any idea why that would occur? and how can I remedy that?

Thanks.

***UPDATED with code***

```
    public string GetOwnedPopulations(string userID)
    {
        Log.TraceEvent(System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Information, string.Format("Entered Method GetOwnedPopulations() CallerNameOnly: {0}, userID: {1} CallerNameOnly==userID {2}", CallerNameOnly, userID, CallerNameOnly == userID), "General");
        this.CallerFullDomain = userID;
        this.CallerNameOnly = userID;// this.CallerFullDomain.Substring(this.CallerFullDomain.IndexOf('\\') + 1);
        string ans;
        Log.TraceEvent(System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Information, string.Format("Entered Method GetOwnedPopulations() CallerNameOnly: {0}, userID: {1} CallerNameOnly==userID {2}", CallerNameOnly , userID, CallerNameOnly==userID), "General");
        searchPopulationbyOwner oReq = new searchPopulationbyOwner();
        oReq.ownerName = this.CallerNameOnly;
        try
        {
            StringBuilder sbBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            PopulationManagementClient client = UPMC.ISD.EADIS.PopulationManagement.PopManSvc.Utils.GetClient(this.CallerNameOnly);
            searchPopulationbyOwnerResponse resp = client.searchPopulationbyOwner(oReq);

            Log.TraceEvent(System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Information, string.Format("Getting Null Values?: {0}", (resp == null ? ans="yes" : ans="no")), "General");

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Population[]));
            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter(sbBuffer);
            xs.Serialize(sw, resp.populationList);


            string sPopulationtXML = sbBuffer.ToString();
            return sPopulationtXML;// client.searchPopulationbyOwner(oReq);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I pass in the username, and I then set the object that I am going to pass in equal to the user ID.  The thing is, userID is either the applicationPoolID, but I am guessing more than likely it is the userPrincipleName (which would happen to be the same as the applicationPoolIdentity... I am not sure if they have to be the same or not).  But this is very weird.  I have know idea why on earth that would be passed in and not the actual username... And yes, I have looked at my site to see what is being passed in, and it is indeed, the userID... When it hits the service however, it is the userPrincipleName.

Confused?????

Comment: Show us the code for the `generalWCFContractImplementation` in your service

Comment: Ok, I didn't do anything except re-upload the DLL's and for some reason it now works.  I probably was running an older version or something.  But I should do some testing before I declare this finished.  But thanks anyway guys.

Comment: Yeah, these kinds of things (older versions) can be annoying at times..... glad it works now! Code seems okay, nothing to complain about...